# Gateway routing failure after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: server, routing, gateway

I've just upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 gateway system to 16.04 and somehow the routing has been broken. The system uses a `pppoe` link to a fibre-modem and runs web, email and DNS services with a `shorewall` configured firewall.

During the update and until next rebooting, networking was working fine.  However, it has since consistently failed to route correctly to the Internet (although internal network routing is fine). Pinging the far end of the `ppp` link does work from the gateway, but external DNS lookups fail.

Routing is configured using the interfaces file, which hasn't changed and looks very boring: one 'internal' network on 192.168.*.* and a `ppp` link using the second Ethernet interface on the machine. None of those configurations has changed. The `ppp` interface has the proper local IP address.

I have checked `sysctl.conf` file and IP forwarding is enabled there. I haven't actually checked that it's set in the kernel.

I may be able to add specific details later -- but I'm not on my home system (because Internet access is broken) so copy/paste isn't easy.

So: is anyone aware of changes in 16.04 that might have caused this, or at least be worthy of further investigation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have an answer of sorts, though I am not sure why.

Originally, my pppd setup included `defaultroute`, but I noticed in the Ubuntu [PPPoE setup guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE) that the base setup included `replacedefaultroute`.

I have added that to the `pppd` peers file, and reinstated other things as they were before, and now it works.

For anyone else in this situation: although the gateway networking worked straight away, I needed to do `shorewall restart` to resume internet access from the internal network.